# installing jdk8 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: jdk

I am completely new to Ubuntu and I want to install jdk8. I downloaded the jdk-8u25linux-x64.tar.gz file from their website, but I wanted to follow a lot YouTube videos but somehow I cannot follow them. lastly I tried with
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729592/how-to-install-jdk-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-using-tar-gz-file

but when I entered

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

and asks for my password, I give the password and press enter and it is blank, nothing happens afterwards.

Please write some step by step solution and solve my problem.

Comment: Ubuntu will not show the characters or asterix's (*) of your password, for security reasons. So it's normal that it does not "write" your password in the terminal. Just to clear out confusion. Other than that, Tobias's answer below is correct.

Comment: my problem is not with the passowrd, after i put it nothing there is noe response from the terminal

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close, you just missed a couple of steps.

Run 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

The first command (which you already ran) adds the personal package archive, the second command updates your list of packages and the third command installs the package.

To verify that you installed the correct version, run `java -version`

Comment: hi, the problem is when i give my password it does not response anything, I hit enter and it remains blank!

Comment: If it did not return your prompt.   That usually means it is working

Comment: As Virusboy said, it it doesn't respond with anything, that usually means success.
Run the next two commands, and then run: java -version
What does that return?

Comment: This method downloads `jdk-8uXXlinux-x64.tar.gz` for you.